# alphanumeric html5 form pattern with space?

Tags: html

Before I came to ask question here I have searched a lot if I can find with space but I was only getting with space alphanumeric which was allowing only numbers too. Here is my pattern I just want it allow space but it be same as it now.

`^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

```html
<form action="#"> 
<input type="text" pattern="^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" required name="naam" class="form-control">
<button type="submit" value="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

That is how I used it working perfect not allowing only numbers but with alphabet it allowing me to submit just problem is when I put space it stop me to submit. that is what I do not want.

Comment: how you can check regex() in html  ? share your code what you tried before or add jsfiddle

Comment: Edited main post

Comment: you can only input number (no space ,no text)

Comment: For me it working like it letting me input number with alphabet or only alphabet but not only numbers. but little more I want to achieve goal is just it let me input space also.

Comment: no below input work with every like number,text and space explain more to understand

Comment: edited main post with submit button you can get result just type abc abc with space

Comment: Not sure if I get your question, but check for alphanumeric / whitespace using this expression: `[\w\s]`

Comment: @LuudJacobs you are right but how may I have added \s but it now allowing only numbers with space too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this code

add `\s` into pattern for `space`

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" pattern="^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&* ]*$" required name="naam" class="form-control">
  <button type="submit" value="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

now try updated `patter`

Comment: quite perfect but now it allowing numbers only if I add space between them. ;/

Comment: You are genius Thank a lot thumps up

Comment: feel free to rate my question if you think it suits on stackoverflow

Comment: oops bro it take one more error I cannot now input 1 month and more numbers with alphabet.